# Html/CSS login system does not work properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use this code I found on internet from codepen.io. But when I implement the html and css I do get some errors. The code isn't perfect right but in the compiler of codepen it does work properly.

I know you can't place a div inside a label tag but I tried diffrence thinks like instead of using div tag using the spand tag. This didn't work propperly either.

Here is the original link to the code https://codepen.io/robcampo/pen/ZGgGow.

This is the code html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><title>

</title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

</head>


<body style="background-image: url('Resources/4k-wallpaper-agriculture-clouds-842711.jpg'); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat">



<style type="text/css">
            input {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label::before {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
label .burger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
label .burger::before,
label .burger .bar, label .burger::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
label .burger .bar {
  top: 44%;
}
label .burger::before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
label .burger::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

input:focus + label .burger,
label:hover .burger {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* material acceleration */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
nav::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 25em;
  background:  #ffa64d;
  content: "";
  transform: skewX(15deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  opacity:0.5;
}
@media (min-width: 40em) {
  nav::before {
    width: 40em;
  }
}
nav a {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.2em 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: color 0.15s, transform 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
nav a:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 100ms;
}
nav a:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 150ms;
}
nav a:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 200ms;
}
nav a:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 250ms;
}
nav a:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 300ms;
}
nav a:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 350ms;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
  color: black;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
main .content {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* material acceleration */
  will-change: transform, filter;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

[id=navcheck]:checked + label::before {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
[id=navcheck]:checked + label .burger::before, [id=navcheck]:checked + label .burger::after {
  width: 141.42%;
}
[id=navcheck]:checked + label .burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
[id=navcheck]:checked + label .burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(50%);
}
[id=navcheck]:checked + label .burger .bar {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}
[id=navcheck]:checked ~ nav {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
[id=navcheck]:checked ~ nav::before {
  transform: skewX(15deg) translateX(0);
}
[id=navcheck]:checked ~ nav a {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
[id=navcheck]:checked ~ main .content {
  transform: translateX(3em);
  transform-origin: left center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  /* quite laggy :S */
}

/* helper */
.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

/* misc */
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
  font: 1em/1.4 "lato";
}

main {
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 5% 0;
}

article {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
@media (min-width: 60em) {
  article {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

h1 {
  font: 2.5em/1.4 "roboto condensed";
  font-weight: 700;
}

            </style>

<input type="checkbox" id="navcheck" role="button" title="menu">
<label for="navcheck" aria-hidden="true" title="menu">
    <span class="burger">
        <span class="bar">
        </span>
    </span>
</label>
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="HomePage.aspx"><img src="Resources/home.png"/></a>
    <a href="HomePage.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="Resources/newtabblad.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Resources/game.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Resources/login.png" /></a>
</nav>


        <div> 

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>


<style type="text/css">

form {
text-align: center;
}

label {
display: block;
letter-spacing: 4px;
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
label .label-text {
color: #9B9B9B;
cursor: text;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
-moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
transform: translateY(-34px);
transition: all 0.3s;
}
label input {
background-color: transparent;
border: 0;
border-bottom: 2px solid #4A4A4A;
color: white;
font-size: 36px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
outline: 0;
padding: 5px 20px;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s;
width: 200px;
}
label input:focus {
max-width: 100%;
width: 400px;
}
label input:focus + .label-text {
color: #F0F0F0;
font-size: 13px;
-moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
transform: translateY(-74px);
}
label input:valid + .label-text {
font-size: 13px;
-moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
transform: translateY(-74px);
}

button {
background-color: #333333;
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 27px;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 15px 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: all 200ms;
}
button:hover, button:focus {
background-color: white;
color: #333333;
outline: 0;
}
}

</style>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
<form>
<label>
<input type="text" required />
<div class="label-text">First name</div>
</label>
<label>
<input type="text" required />
<div class="label-text">Last name</div>
</label>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>


        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry I wasn't clear about the errors I did get, let me provide them to you.
When I do run this code I get: div cannot be nested inside label. Furthermore the placement in my screen isn't right everythink is cropped up in the left upper corner. And there are not any textfield where I could put in some test. Hope this provide the right errors

Hope you could help me with this "log in system"

Thanks in adavance

hope this works it says I am not allowed to add images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fLcg.png)

Comment: "_But when I implement the html and css I do get some errors_" - What errors are you getting from HTML/CSS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're going to have to provide a lot more details. What *specifically* isn't working? What have you tried in order to fix it, and why didn't it work. You should probably delete this question, and create a new one that asks a specific question that can be answered; as it is right now, your question is far too broad

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the feed back I edditen them in.

Comment: Please show all of your html code including the linked stylesheets.

Comment: I see several issues with the code.  There is a mismatched closing `</div>` tag at the end before the closing body tag.  There is a mismatched closing `}` bracket at the end of second style section.

Comment: Switch your `<div>` tags inside your labels to `<span>` tags and it should stop complaining about that.

Comment: Here is what I did.  I copied your html code and your second section of CSS code into a new pen and it worked beautifully.  https://codepen.io/dmikester1/pen/MxWmLE  Now when I copied in your first section of CSS, it hosed it all up.  Your first section of CSS up above is messing it up.  Get rid of that.

Comment: @dmikester1 thanks for the notice did changed them! Also did the span tag it fixed the "error" but didn't fix the problem but thank will try now the last one

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the OP had targeted the elements by the element names, which were being mixed up for two different purposes. Targeting the elements by classes or IDs seems to provide the solution.

Comment: Actually `<html>` and `<head>` are not required in HTML5 anymore.

Comment: Oh! thanks for telling. I just discovered it now. I'll edit answer for the same

Comment: It seems to work perfectly for me. Can you post the code you added?

Comment: mhmm strange I added these two lines     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` to link the CSS for your page if your index.html and style.css are in the same folder, otherwise replace *style.css* by the path of the CSS file

Comment: Does your code look like [this](https://repl.it/repls/RegalLowestPython)??

Comment: nope bcs I cant do <div> inside a <label> when I do I get "div cannot be nested inside label"

Comment: can you clarify what **exactly** you want the code to do? Because the codepen link has this code only.

Comment: I copied 1 on 1 you code the css and the html but in the html my <div> get an error saying : "validation (html5) element div cannot be nested within element label"
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <form>
    <label>
    <input type="text" required />
    <div class="label-text">First name</div>
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="text" required />
    <div class="label-text">Last name</div>
    </label>
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: can you post the screenshot of how the page renders in the browser?

Comment: @Natasha thanks for your help!! how could I post a ss?

Comment: Edit your question and click on the picture icon to select the image you want.

Comment: added it the picture in the original post couldn't make it from the whole screen it was to big

Comment: Can you post the final code you wrote after editing?

Comment: just editten the original codes with the ones I have now

Comment: I don't think it is the complete HTML code. It would be required to see how the DOM elements are arranged.

Comment: It would probably be best to show the rendered code that is sent to the browser.  Right click in your browser and hit "view source" and paste that code as the HTML up above.

Comment: The code seems to work perfectly fine without the extra code for the menu. There is a very high possibility that the some of the style definitions for the other `<label>` elements (in the menu) are being applied to the ones in the login. You have used `label` in CSS to target *all* the labels. So the code required for other labels is also considered for the login ones.Try to instead target the elements by other specifiers like classes or ids

Comment: Thanks! I think that is indeed the answer let me try it. For now thank you so much